# How to choose the parameters of the prior distribution of binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, prior, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I've faced a problem like this:

In an election there are 2 candidates, we know that every person's vote is a Bernoulli random variable and we know that the votes of the candidates in the society is equal.

I want to use Beta distribution as prior distribution to guess p. How should I choose the parameters of this Beta distribution?

Comment: What kind of prior beliefs about p do you have?

Comment: @Tim We know that the society votes equally to both candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being Bayesian means that *you* pick *your* prior from *your* subjective beliefs OR as a reference that you can later calibrate if need be. There is no "true" or even "good" choice for a prior, even within a parameterised family, as for instance a Beta $\text{B}(a,b)$ prior on the probability $p$. Namely, there is no single choice for the hyperparameters $a$ and $b$ until you define the purpose of choosing a prior, an issue that is somewhat outside the Bayesian framework. (Even though priors can be compared by the use of a Bayes factor, but this is not 100% orthodox.)

From a Bayesian perspective, the resulting posterior analysis is determined by the prior and relative to this prior. This means in particular that the probabilistic statements based on that posterior are relative, rather than absolute, which explains or may explain the distinction between frequentist and Bayesian probabilistic statements.